# How to send mail from MS Access Form

Tags: email, ms-access

How to send a mail from MS Access Form. ?

Assume I have MS Access Application with a DashBoard form. 
I have send mails to certain mail address
like sending a notification mail on clicking "send notification button"
How to do this with codebuilder in MS access

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that you can send mail using this code snippet

```
Private Sub send_mail()

   Dim olApp As Object
   Dim objMail As Object

   On Error Resume Next 'Keep going if there is an error
   Set olApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application") 'See if Outlook is open

    If Err Then 'Outlook is not open
       Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application") 'Create a new instance 
    End If
  'Create e-mail item
   Set objMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

   With objMail
   'Set body format to HTML
     .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
     .To = "abc@yourmailaddress.com"
     .Cc ="ccaddress@yourmailaddress.com"
     .Subject = "Subject LIne"
     .HTMLBody = "<htmltags>Body Content</htmltags>"
     .send
   End With

  MsgBox "Operation completed successfully"

 End Sub
```

Source : [Thread from Access Programmer site](http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=193374)

Answer (score 0):

I found some code that worked for email based on code that I was using to open a browser from a contact's home page, worked just fine and was a lot easier for me to understand.  For opening a web page, delete the '"mailto:" & '.

```
Private Sub cmdEmailContact_Click()
Dim sWebPath As String
Dim sFullLinkPath As String

If IsNull(Me.ContactEmail) Then
    MsgBox ("Can't create email: no address listed")
    Exit Sub
End If

sWebPath = "mailto:" & Me.ContactEmail

sFullLinkPath = sWebPath
Application.FollowHyperlink sFullLinkPath

End Sub
```